# How to pass data between safari session and ios app

Tags: swift, firebase, safari, firebase-authentication

I am building an iOS app with a web component. The web component will simply be a website that will allow users without accounts to perform a basic action like sending text to another user. I am using firebase as my backend so for the web component I'm anonymously authenticating the visitor. Once the user completes the action, I log their action in a database (hence the need for authentication) and give them the option of downloading the app, where they will make an account. My plan is to then convert their anonymous account into a permanent account on firebase.

The problem lies in the following:

I want to somehow "know" the user's authUID/web session once they leave the site and download the app in order to either a) pass their anonymous session and convert it to a permanent account once the user completes the sign up (email, password), or b) have their authUID so I can match them to their anonymous session and transfer their logs to the account they create upon sign up.

I feel like I'm overcomplicating this; the premise is: web visitor does something, downloads the app, i match the app user to the web visitor to sync their data.

I have tried using cookies but from what I've read, it is not possible to view cookies in safari since iOS 11. Is there any other way to transfer information between safari and an app?

Comment: Can't you give them a one-time code that they fill in on the App to skip other authentication?

Comment: i havent tried it myself so i have no idea if it works or not, but have you tried deeplinking? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW11